# How to get access to a different object through a variable storing Django Max object?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a Django model called Bids with the following objects: listing, bid, and user. I am trying to get access to the user with the largest bid. How do you do that?

I am currently trying:

```py
winning_bid = Bids.objects.aggregate(Max('bid'))
winner = winning_bid.user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the `Bids` with the largest `bid` with [**`.latest(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest):

```
winning_bid = Bids.objects.latest('bid')
winner = winning_bid.user
```

You can boost efficiency with [**`.select_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to load the user details in the same query:

```
winning_bid = Bids.objects.select_related('user').latest('bid')
winner = winning_bid.user
```